# Weird table rendering in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, html-table, windows-8.1

I use Firefox 26.0 on Windows 8.1. The simple tabular html+css layout is rendered strangely on different zoom levels.

100% zoom in Firefox is ok. IE and Chrome render the document properly. Changing html code to regular table/tr/td doesn't help.

Is it a bug in the Firefox on Windows 8.1 or something wrong with the layout?

**HTML code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="board">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="cell"></div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
            <div class="cell"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS code**

```
#board {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
}

.cell {
    border: 1px solid;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
}
```

**Results:**

100% -2 zoom out:

[image: 100%-2]

100% -3 zoom out:

[image: 100%-3]

100% +1 zoom in:

[image: 100%+1]

100% +3 zoom in:

[image: 100%+3]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*From Bugzilla :*

> Bug 410959 - [BC] Table cell border widths render incorrectly at
>   various zoom levels

That's a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=410959) and no one has yet solved it.

---

Also, if you are having a tabular data, use `table` and not `div`

---

And the solution for this is to use `border-collapse: separate;`

```
#board {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

<s>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CFm33/1/)</s> *(Your buggy demo on zoom in and out using `border-collapse: collapse;`)*

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/CFm33/)

Comment: Thank you for quick and comprehensive answer!